# Utility-based portfolio optimization

Tags: portfolio-optimization, utility-theory

I think I can't get the idea of optimization based on utility. For some reasons, I should choose one of several common utility functions (exponential, isoelastic function and some others). Obviously, in it's formal representation as 1-exp(-a*Profit)- a (risk-aversion) doesn't make any sense in maximization. So, should any function be expanded by Taylor series, for example until 4th moment of distribution? Like this:[image]

Would be glad if you could help me with this. I'm especially interested in isoelastic function. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is the *expected utility* that you maximize, not the utility itself. In general you will have an integral of the product of utility times probability. That can be complicated, so people sometimes do a Taylor expansion in terms of moments, like you are suggesting. Another way is a Monte Carlo simulation where you generate 1000 utilities of random returns and take the average.

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea with the expectation, now it is pretty clear.
Can you please expand more on Monte-Carlo method for this problem? What do you mean by random returns? In my study I have simulated 10,000 returns from copula-garch method for 50 weeks. Can I somehow use them here?